# Disable Clipboard & Print Screen on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

i search online but can't get satisfactory result

i want to protect images on my website, i know i can disable save as, right click.

the real question is can we Disable Clipboard & Print Screen with JQUERY or java script.

so no image copy from print screen.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop User from using "Print Scrn" / "Printscreen" key of the Keyboard for any Web Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I am pretty sure you can't do that. Print screen is a part of the OS, not the browser. I would hope that web sites weren't able to mess with my OS like that.

You can certainly throw roadblocks in front of people trying to download an image, but short of watermarking, there isn't a great way to prevent people from getting your image (that I know of) if you make it available online.

Answer (score 3):

Not from a webpage.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you were able to disable these from within a browser, it will only stop a casual user.  If you make a resource available on a public server (as you must in order to let a casual user view it), there really is no way to stop someone from retrieving that resource.  After all, you actually *want* the user to retrieve the resource.

Answer (score 1):

No you can´t. And you can´t disable right click in a bullet proof way either.

The only way to *protect* your images is by watermark them.

Answer (score 1):

Print Screen is a function of the operating system, and as such, cannot be disable by a webpage.

Actually, you can't disable anything. I know you technically can, but most browsers have an option to not allow disabling of those things. And really, worst case scenario, anyone can view the source of your site and copy the image's url.

In short, don't worry about it so much. Some people will copy your images, but this is nothing new on the internet, so you'll just have to learn to live with it. The only thing that any of your work will do is annoy some people, and make other people have to try a little bit. So, it's really best to not do anything. Place a copyright notice on your site and most people won't try to blatantly steal from you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do what you're requesting is to incorporate OS-embedded DRM into your content (think HDCP). This can prevent even screenshots from being done but will **severely** limit your audience and is an **absolutely horrible** idea - don't do it!

If you really want to protect your images, the best way to do it is with watermarks and providing very low-quality images on your website and the high-quality stuff in some other way. The watermarks aren't a perfect solution but many consider them good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no direct way to do that, but I used javascript to hide the content whenever the user hovers outside the website. This forces the user to actually **activate** your page to be able to see its content. This will activate the javascript that prevents prnt scrn too.

Comment: The article link is dead ... is it still available?