# How to disable the print screen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I trying to build website based on images. That's why I am trying to disable user's print screen through JavaScript. But it is not working in all browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's beyond your control, because print screen is not a browser feature it's a system feature.

Answer (score 1):

eventually, you could listen keydown, if printscreen key code is catchable, you could display a full white element over everything so it would print a white screen...

Comment: `keydown` will be fired after the screen is captured so it won't be useful.