# How to overwrite clipboard every five seconds?

Tags: clipboard, zeroclipboard, zclip, clipboardmanager, clipboarddata

I'm trying to prevent users to copy some sensitive data from my internal portal. I have disabled copy paste everything, but I cant disable print screen so I decided to empty clipboard every five seconds so that contents copied will be useless but cant use `zeroclipboard.swf` without a button trigger

Here is the code

```
<script>
    setInterval ("doSomething()", 1000);
    function doSomething()
      { 
      document.getElementById("btn_copy").click();
      }

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cop").zclip({
       path:"ZeroClipboard.swf",
       copy:"This is arasu"
    });
});
```

If I click the button it works, but it isn't working, when it is triggered with coding

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Screw that. I didn't see that it was in html.

However you know that you are just increasing the difficulty of taking snapshots since programs like snagit don't need the clipboard to take screenshots.

Comment: exactly people will do but at least we can stop some of them know, anyhow thanks for response and i found a correct solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we